# how to use the same ColorChooserButton to perform two different actions

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcolorchooser

I am using a Swing color picker to change the color of drawn shapes, the problem is I want to use the same `colorChooserwindow` and same button `choose` to perform 2 different actions, either filling the shape or changing the shape line color but I cannot differentiate which button was clicked before (`fillColor` or `lineColor`) I know that I should add something to the `ColorChooserWindow` constructor to tell it which kind of color is being chosen but I cannot figure it out I tried an `ActionEvent` and `getSource()` method but it doesn't work

```
/** this is my constructor**/

/**
 * Creates new form ColorPickerWindow
 */
public ColorPickerWindow(DrawingModel model) {
    // save the model
    myModel = model;
    // window title 
    this.setTitle("Color Picker");
    initComponents();

}

/** and this is the action performed method **/

private void chooseColorButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {        


    // TODO add your handling code here:

    DrawingWindow dw = new DrawingWindow(myModel);
    myModel.setFillColor(jColorChooser.getColor());
    dw.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Hello rana88, you seem to be new to Stack Overflow. I already improved your question's readability but it's still not a good question for the site. Please, could you follow the next steps for us to be more able to help you? Take the [tour], read [ask] and then what a [mcve], create one and post it. Because with your current code we cannot provide much help. We need a sample code created by you that we can copy / paste / compile / test and see the same behavior as you (with little to no modifications) This way you'll get more, faster and better answers. Thank you

Comment: Also your question is a little bit confusing, you're saying you want a single button to perform 2 different actions, but then you mention you want to differentiate between 2 buttons, which one is correct? 1 button and 2 actions? Or 2 buttons that choose a color and perform a different action? Could you post what "doesn't work" with the `ActionEvent` and `getSource()`? It seems odd that it doesn't work, so this is something you're doing wrong but we don't like to guess, and to be accurate we need that MCVE.